# Android: Upgrade from Material 1.0 causing problems

Tags: java, android, gradle, material-design, material-components-android

I recently upgraded from material 1.0 to material 1.1 to be able to use the new `TabLayoutMediator`.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

That worked out. However, I am now facing weird UI issues since the upgrade.

[[image: Picture of some bugs[1]]

I've included four issues in the picture. The issues are:

1. MaterialButtons have a black border. Before the upgrade they had no border.
2. Material FloatingActionsButtons suddenly have black icons. Before the upgrade the icons were white.
3. The navigation icons are black too. Before the upgrade those icons were greyish.
4. Textfields are deformed beyond recognition

Now, I find it odd that such a minor update can cause such weird issues. What's also weird is that I tried some manual fixes - like changing the tint of the FloatingActionButton to get a white icon again - but those manual fixes don't seem to work.

What's the cause of this issues and how do I fix it? I've considered going back to material 1.0 ....

---

**Update**

My app theme:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/GlobalTextViewStyle</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

My MaterialButton:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
                app:cornerRadius="6dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_max="400dp"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

---

**Update #2**

I fixed everything so far by manually changing the colors. It seems like the default values have changed in material 1.1. However, the Textfields still cause problems. This is the code I use for adding them:

```java
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(view.getContext());
textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textInputLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 40);

TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(view.getContext());
editText.setHint(getVerboseName());
textInputLayout.addView(editText);
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
```

Comment: It is quite strange. What is your app theme? Can you post the layout of the MaterialButton?

Comment: I updated my question with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright to conclude:

The manual fixes do indeed work, one just needs to make sure to use proper Material Styles. The four bugs are not related to each other. The fourth bug was caused by me not giving the EditText within the TextInputLayout the context of the TextInputLayout but rather the context of the fragment itself.

If anyone else faces issues like this, they are separate issues and should be treated as such. The upgrade to Material 1.1 introduced new default values - not bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> MaterialButtons have a black border. Before the upgrade they had no border.

In your MaterialButton:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

- there is `app:strokeWidth="2dp"`: **remove** it.
- You are using an AppCompat theme. Change it to `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks to your help I was able to fix the issues except for one. The TextFields are still buggy. I updated my question.